# Issues with installing Splashtop Streamer, (Beta)

Tags: software-recommendation, software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and this forum too, so sorry if I break any posting rules or asking a stupid question.

I'm trying to install Splashtop Streamer, on Ubuntu 14.04, However I get the following error message.

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Details:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
splashtop-streamer: Depends: libx264-123 but it is not going to be installed
```

Can anyone help? Or recommend something to remote desktop from Android to Ubuntu 14.04

Regards Richard

Answer (score 1):

There is a working solution [here](https://support-splashtoppersonal.splashtop.com/entries/43459488-Splashtop-personal-can-t-be-installed-on-ubuntu-14-04?page=1#post_25375757).

From the above link, as stated by Northreigh:

Download : [libavutil51_0.8.10-1_amd64.deb](http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/liba/libav/libavutil51_0.8.10-1_amd64.deb)

Install the downloaded deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/lib*
```

Now , installing `splashtop` via Software Center should work.

Start splashtop via command-line as launcher icon failed to work:

```
python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc
```